Testing Teams Toolkit App - Testing App in environment Locally works but not in Dev or Production
I debug my application using the different environments, Our Published Teams Tab app is currently not working, and we are trying to ascertain why. When I test it in the local environment it works, then the failed published app starts to work. I assume it's because the app can read the Manifest.js file put into memory.
Do I just have to republish the app created, or is there something else at play with the manifest.js file?
I checked to see if there were any errors, in the code I tried to add a web part.
Images

Production Error on Teams
Debugging In Local Environment
Debugging In Local Environment VS Code
SP Webpart in debug mode


I don't think your local app will have impact on the published one. For local env, the web part is hosted in local server while the published one is getting things from SPO. The 'Production Error on Teams' looks weird and shouldn't be the one for published app. You could retry and see whether you still have the same issue. Please feel free to raise an issue to us if you have further questions.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I agree , hence me asking for assitance

Please let us know if you still have the issue and feel free to raise GitHub issue to us where we can better track the problem.

@user26379880 Would like to follow up with you if you still have the issue
